# Conectar Yii2 con base de datos en SQLite

Tags: php, sqlite, yii2, yii

Estoy tratando de conectar mi aplicacion en Yii2 con una BD en Yii2 hasta el momento esta es la configuracion que tengo en mi archivo .db

```
return [
             'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
            'dsn' => 'sqlite:' . __DIR__  .'/../../softwareoperacional.db',
            ];
```

Comment: Tiene algún problema, ¿te marca algun error?

Comment: No me muestra ningún error solo que no se si esta bien conectada o no

Comment: ¿Has verificado hacer alguna consulta?

Answer (score 0):

sobre tu archivo de configuración `main.php` ó `main-local.php`
la configuración a manejar sería

```
return [
// ...
'components' => [
        .....
        'db' => [
            'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
            'dsn' => 'sqlite:/miDB.db',
        ],
        .....
    ],
];
```

el archivo de la base de datos debe de tener permisos de lectura y escritura para realizar operaciones necesarias como `SELECT` e `INSERT`, puedes encontrar más información en la siguiente liga http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-dao.html

toma en cuenta que debes de tener instalada la extensión de sqlite para que funcione.

Comment: Ahora si me sale un error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW) in C:\xampp\htdocs\basic\config\db.php on line 27

Comment: que usas, yii o yii2, porque son algo distintos

Comment: Estoy utilizando Yii2

Comment: Si tienes un fichero para solo la configuración de la base de datos, puedes solo retornar el arreglo que tú colocaste(asegura que esté leyendo dicho fichero para setear el valor de la base de datos al aplicativo), si tienes un fichero `main.php`, debes de colocar dentro de la directiva `'components'`.

Comment: Tengo un archivo de configuracion db.php